# Find a value inside an object CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Im trying to find a value inside a object, but I cant seem to get what isset is doing. Maybe Im using it wrong. I have two objects and what Im trying to do is delete the row which is not in the second object. 
Here is the object 1:

```
    Array ( 
    [idCategory1] => 1 
    [idCategory2] => 2 
    [idCategory4] => 4 
)
```

And here is object 2:

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [CategoriesProvider] => Array ( 
            [id] => 28 
            [provider_id] => 2 
            [category_id] => 1 
            [created] => 2015-03-13 20:25:17 
            [modified] => 2015-03-13 20:25:17 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [CategoriesProvider] => Array ( 
            [id] => 29 
            [provider_id] => 2 
            [category_id] => 2 
            [created] => 2015-03-13 20:25:17 
            [modified] => 2015-03-13 20:25:17 
        ) 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [CategoriesProvider] => Array ( 
            [id] => 30 
            [provider_id] => 2 
            [category_id] => 4 
            [created] => 2015-03-13 20:25:17 
            [modified] => 2015-03-13 20:25:17 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Here is my code to delete the row of object 2 which is not in object 1.

```
 foreach ($CategoriesOfProvider as $key ) {
    if(isset($CategoriesProvider['CategoriesProvider']->$key['CategoriesProvider']['category_id'])) {

    }  else {
        $this->User->Provider->CategoriesProvider->id = $key['CategoriesProvider']['id'];
        //$this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->User->Provider->CategoriesProvider->delete()) {

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> No se pudo borrar la relacion producto - categoría.',
                'default',
                array('class' => 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible', 'type' => 'alert')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`$CategoriesOfProvider` is object 2 and `$CategoriesProvider` is object 1. So Im trying to use isset to find if the id in object 2 is in the value of the object 1. I think Im using isset wrong. Or is there another way? I thought of maybe run it against each of the values of object 1. Would that work better?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do it. I stopped using isset and instead use another foreach and went through all the values in object 1. If it wasnt found then I deleted the extra category. Here is the code.

```
$this->User->Provider->CategoriesProvider->recursive = -1;
$CategoriesOfProvider = $this->User->Provider->CategoriesProvider->find('all', array( 'conditions'=> array('CategoriesProvider.provider_id' => $provider_id ) ) );

//echo print_r($CategoriesProvider);
//return print_r($CategoriesOfProvider);

foreach ($CategoriesOfProvider as $key ) {
    $found = false;
    //if(isset($CategoriesProvider['CategoriesProvider']->$key['CategoriesProvider']['category_id'])) {
    foreach ($CategoriesProvider as $key1 => $value) {
        if($key['CategoriesProvider']['category_id'] == $value) {
            $found = true;
        }  
    }

    if($found) {

    }  else {
        $this->User->Provider->CategoriesProvider->id = $key['CategoriesProvider']['id'];
        //$this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->User->Provider->CategoriesProvider->delete()) {

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> No se pudo borrar la relacion producto - categoría.',
                'default',
                array('class' => 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible', 'type' => 'alert')
            );
        }
    }

}
```

I hope it helps someone :P